# Five ways to say Yes in Stack Exchangish

Tags: discussion, network-profile, subscription

1. yee-haw
2. sure
3. yes-please
4. why-not
5. of-course

Want to see for yourself? Here are the steps to uncover it!

1. Subscribe to any tag (email subscription, available when you hover the tag name)
2. Go to your network profile
3. Click "subscription" tab
4. Check the URL of the "manage" link. It would be something like: `http://stackexchange.com/filters/2541/asp-classic?subscribe=yes-please`
5. The word after "subscribe" would be random, one of the above five.

Hard to believe? [Watch for yourself](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=IPDuigVJVSQ)! ;-)

Oh, so what's the question here? Well, as I strongly suspect it's a leftover from the development phase that reached production by mistake, think it's time to remove it. Nothing against some fun but...

Comment: I would rather think of it as an easter egg, and it is here to stay.

Comment: FEATURE REQUEST: add 6. `subscribe=hell-yeah`

Comment: If this is a 'feature request', I'm down-voting it!!! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber yeah, figured out many would object so left it as discussion to see where the wind is blowing first... :-)

Comment: FEATURE REQUEST for #7: `subscribe=yeeeeaaaaaahhhh`

Comment: #8 subscribe=you-didnt-mean-to-click-on-that-did-you-you-twat